# Bottom slider on navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation

I want that the border below the navigation always follows the mouse coursur if the coursor hovers over the navigation.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined
```

### JS Code

```
$(function() {
  var $el, leftPos, newWidth,
      $mainNav = $(".level_1");

  $mainNav.append("<div id='magic-line'></div>");
  var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

  $magicLine
    .width($(".active").width())
    .css("left", $(".active a").position().left)
    .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
    .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

  $(".level_1 li a").hover(function() {
    $el = $(this);
    leftPos = $el.position().left;
    newWidth = $el.parent().width();
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
      left: leftPos,
      width: newWidth
    });

  }, function() {
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
      left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
      width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
    });    
  });

  $('.level_1 li:not(".active")').hover(
    function(){ $('#magic-line').addClass('hover'); },
    function(){ $('#magic-line').removeClass('hover'); }
  );
});
```

### HTML

```
<nav class="mod_customnav block" id="top-nav">

  <ul class="level_1">
    <li class="first"><a href="de/ueber-uns" title="Über uns" class="first">Über uns</a></li>
    <li><a href="de/kontakt" title="Kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li class="active"><span class="active">Impressum</span></li>
    <li><a href="en/" title="English">English</a></li>
    <li><a href="fr/" title="Français">Français</a></li>
    <li class="navSearch icon last"><a href="de/suche" title="" class="navSearch icon last">Suche</a></li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

If someone could help me, that would be awsome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
$(".active a").position().left
```

At the moment you don't have an anchor inside your li or span with a class of active so this will be undefined

try

```
$(".active span").position().left
```

**EDIT**

You can check the length of active to solve your problem:

```
var active = $(".active");
if (active.length) {
    $magicLine
        .width(active.width())
        .css("left", active.children('span').position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());
} else {
    $magicLine
        .width(WIDTH_HERE)
        .css("left", LEFT_HERE)
}
```